# Upload image,and some text with Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, canvas

I'm trying to upload image and 2 values from text fields, but I can't use a input type="file" for resource becouse I first choose file using camera capture and preview image in `<img ...`, after that I replace the src of image tag with resized image (max 500kb) and that image I try to upload. If I use a input type="file" , than I upload a first Image, not a resized. Any sugestions ?

Comment: Some code might be useful. It will make it easier to understand exactly what you're doing

Comment: take a look on jquery.form.js they have great solutions for image and ajax http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: main problem is that i can't upload image without using input type=file, I'm trying to uplad directly from src of image..

Comment: You can't programmatically set a file input. Try drawing the image to a canvas then get the image as a data uri then upload that.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I don't now how to put together a file, and text  programmatically..If you have a example or tutorial for that It will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the cam image and transfer it (base64 encoded) independent from the form to your server. Or put the base64 encoded image into a hidden input.